# Xpath contains string

Tags: selenium, xpath

I just started working with Selenium and I'm facing quite a problem. I'm working with a dynamic website and I want Selenium to always click the top link of the page. All links start with the following xpath

```
//*[@id='rList:0:itemFormClassic']/div[2]/h2/span/a
```

I now would like to know if my `xpath` starts with the string `'rList:0:itemFormClassic']/div`, so I type in

```
//*[starts-with(@id, ''rList:0:itemFormClassic']/div')]
```

But this doesn't work, because the symbol `'` that is already included in my `xpath` is seen as my actual string I want to compare.

Does anyone know how I can avoid that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Selenium, but did you try `&quot;` to escape the `'`?

Comment: Have you tried to use double quotes to include the string? Why would you check if the xpaths starts with? Do you need a selector for elements with id that starts with rList ?

Comment: try as : `//*[starts-with(@id, "'rList:0:itemFormClassic']/div")]`..But are you sure your element id is starts with `'rList:0:itemFormClassic']/div`...??

Comment: You can locate link by `driver.findElement(By.tagName("a"));`. This will always locate the first link in the DOM. You can also, use `driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"))[0];` to select the first link. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes and escaping.
This should work:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, \"'rList:0:itemFormClassic]/div\")]"));
```